# Laravel 5.3 authentication from other API, without database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth

In my laravel5.3 app I want to authenticate users from Other source, i.e. without database in My side. I expected JSON response from other source, after login attempt. Can anyone explain how I can do this??? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this you should have some info about the external API you want to use with your example, the most important piece of information is: "How is encrypted the users password in that server?", with that, you only need to get the credentials passed from the frontend, then in your backend ask for a user to the external API, let's say you are using guzzle, you make guzzle to ask a resource `/users/<username>`, this service will provide all the data from the API if the user exists, otherwise the response will be not found or something like that, with this data, you can encrypt the password using the same crypt technique of the external server, and match the password, by using the `Hash::check($value, $hashedValue)` method, if everything goes fine, then the next thing you can do is just login the user using a Guard, maybe you need to create a custom Guard in order to store the credentials in a cookie or a session variable, but if you are using stateless authentication via JWT, is even easier, when you compare the password provided with the stored in the external API, if this returns true, just create the token and return it. Consider to use JWT to authenticate your services' user in your app, is easier and is more suitable to your situation, hope you solve with this answer, bests! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like a normal AJAX call u will do in any other website :
e.g:

```
$('#selector').click(function(){

        var user-id=$('#user').val();
        var password=$('#password').val();
        $.getJSON('/authenticate-url/'+user+'/'+password, function(result) {
           if(result.status == true)
              alert 'login success';
           else
              alert 'Not successfull';

        });
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I cannot explain what I want, but I know how to call to API's, I want to LOGIN user in My app from AJAX response, but I have'nt database in my side.... Ajax call give me response with login information of user, for example {"user":"test","login":"true"}

Comment: After Response I must login user to my laravel app, but I really don't understand how I can do that

Comment: ok so where exactly you want to call this api , in the view right ?

Comment: It's No matter where i want to call.... I don't know how to use Auth::login() with JSON response params

Comment: if the database is not on your side , why you are taking Auth login into consideration ?

Comment: my app's data must save in other server... but that server has its own API, and return json on api call, so i want to call to their api on login attempt, then login user in my app with json response!!